# What is the origin of 'tenting' or 'roofing' in NMR spectra?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

Given an NMR spectrum with two coupled nuclei one can often observe so-called 'roofing' – an asymmetry in the multiplet.

For example, here is a 300 MHz proton spectrum of 1-bromo-2-methoxyethane, where the inset shows the triplets corresponding to the adjacent $\ce{CH2}$ groups:

[image: Proton NMR spectrum of 1-bromo-2-methoxyethane]

(Source: [Hans Reich, University of Wisconsin](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/05-hmr-09-2ndorder.htm))

What is the origin of that effect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not just coupled, but *strongly* coupled; these roofing effects tend to be seen when the coupling constant $J$ is on the order of $\Delta \nu$ (the difference in resonance frequencies between the two spins).

---

The origin is quantum mechanical in nature. I will try to give a simplified overview of what is happening without going into the explicit details. For a pair of coupled spin-1/2 nuclei, labelled 1 and 2, the Hamiltonian in a magnetic field is

$$\hat{H} = \omega_1\hat{I}_{\!1z} + \omega_2\hat{I}_{\!2z} + 2\pi J(\vec{I}_{\!1}\cdot\vec{I}_{\!2})$$

If the spins are not coupled at all, then

$$\hat{H} = \omega_1\hat{I}_{\!1z} + \omega_2\hat{I}_{\!2z}$$

and the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are exactly

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Eigenstate} & \text{Value of }m_1 & \text{Value of }m_2 \\ \hline
|\alpha\alpha\rangle & +1/2 & +1/2 \\
|\alpha\beta\rangle & +1/2 & -1/2 \\
|\beta\alpha\rangle & -1/2 & +1/2 \\
|\beta\beta\rangle & -1/2 & -1/2
\end{array}$$

NMR theory dictates that only transitions with $\Delta M = \pm 1$ are observable, where $M$ is the sum of the quantum numbers $m_1$ and $m_2$. For example, $|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\alpha\beta\rangle$ is an observable transition ($\Delta M = \pm 1$), but $|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\beta\beta\rangle$ is unobservable ($\Delta M = \pm 2$). From the table above one can see that there are four observable transitions:

$$|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\alpha\beta\rangle; |\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\beta\alpha\rangle; |\alpha\beta\rangle \leftrightarrow |\beta\beta\rangle; |\beta\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\beta\beta\rangle$$

Each transition corresponds to a fixed energy, and hence each observable transition gives rise to one peak in the NMR spectrum. The area under the peak - or loosely speaking, the height of the peak - is related to *how much* "$\Delta M = \pm 1$ character" there is in each transition. Of course, there is a way to formalise this, but for the sake of simplicity that will have to be omitted.

For the transition $|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\beta\beta\rangle$, this is *entirely* $\Delta M = \pm 2$. So, the amount of "$\Delta M = \pm 1$ character" is exactly zero, and the transition is entirely unobservable.

On the other hand, for all four of the allowed transitions, the amount of "$\Delta M = \pm 1$ character" is exactly one, and hence all transitions have equal intensity. [Of course, because of the lack of coupling, there will be two *degenerate* pairs (i.e. there are two pairs of transitions with the same energy), and so you get two singlets in the spectrum.]

---

Now, as the coupling term $2\pi J(\vec{I}_{\!1}\cdot\vec{I}_{\!2})$ 
becomes larger and larger, the eigenstates are gradually shifted away from these. These can be expressed in terms of linear combinations of the four original eigenstates. Without proof I will present the results

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{New eigenstate} & \text{Expression in terms of old eigenstates} \\ \hline
|1\rangle & |\alpha\alpha\rangle \\
|2\rangle & \cos\theta|\alpha\beta\rangle + \sin\theta|\beta\alpha\rangle \\
|3\rangle & -\sin\theta|\alpha\beta\rangle + \cos\theta|\beta\alpha\rangle \\
|4\rangle & |\beta\beta\rangle
\end{array}$$

where $\theta$ is defined by $\tan(2\theta) \equiv J/\Delta\nu$. As the ratio of $J$ to $\Delta\nu$ goes from zero to infinity, $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/4$. It is easy to verify that the *deviation* from the old eigenstates increases as this ratio $J/\Delta\nu$ increases.

Let's look at the transition $|1\rangle \leftrightarrow |2\rangle$. How much "$\Delta M = \pm 1$ character" is there here? Since $|2\rangle$ is a mixture of $|\alpha\beta\rangle$ and $|\beta\alpha\rangle$, the transition $|1\rangle \leftrightarrow |2\rangle$ can be thought of to be a "mixture" of $|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\alpha\beta\rangle$ and $|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\beta\alpha\rangle$.

So, there is $\cos\theta$ amount of "$\Delta M = \pm 1$ character" arising from the $|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\alpha\beta\rangle$ contribution; and there is also $\sin\theta$ amount of "$\Delta M = \pm 1$ character" from the $|\alpha\alpha\rangle \leftrightarrow |\beta\alpha\rangle$ contribution, for a total of $\cos\theta + \sin\theta$.

For quantum mechanical reasons it is necessary to take the square of this quantity, i.e.

$$\begin{align}
(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^2 &= \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta + 2\sin\theta\cos\theta \\
&= 1 + \sin(2\theta)
\end{align}$$

and working through the list of transitions, one finds that the amount of "$\Delta M = \pm 1$ character" for each transition is

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{Transition} & \text{Amount of “}\Delta M = \pm 1\text{ character"} \\ \hline
|1\rangle \leftrightarrow |2\rangle & 1 + \sin(2\theta) \\
|1\rangle \leftrightarrow |3\rangle & 1 - \sin(2\theta) \\
|2\rangle \leftrightarrow |4\rangle & 1 + \sin(2\theta) \\
|3\rangle \leftrightarrow |4\rangle & 1 - \sin(2\theta)
\end{array}$$

Aha! So, as long as $2\theta = \tan^{-1}(J/\Delta\nu) \neq 0$, the intensities of the peaks will be different. There will be two strong peaks (those with plus signs), and two weaker peaks (the minus signs).

When the ratio $J/\Delta\nu$ is small, i.e. the *weak coupling* limit, then $\sin(2\theta)$ is small and the difference in intensity is hardly noticeable - not something that you can tell by eye. For example, in a $\pu{400 MHz}$ spectrometer, two protons that have a chemical shift difference of $\pu{1 ppm}$ would have $\Delta \nu = \pu{400 Hz}$. If we take $J = \pu{7 Hz}$, then $2\theta = \tan^{-1}(7/400) = \pu{0.0175 rad}$ and we have $\sin(2\theta) = 0.0175$, a difference which you'd be hard pressed to spot!

But when this ratio increases, the value of $\sin(2\theta)$ will increase, and the difference in intensity will become more and more pronounced. I won't go into the maths, but it is possible to show that the *middle two* transitions have the higher intensity, and the *outer two* transitions have the lower intensity - which, of course, gives rise to the "roofing effect" which you speak of.